# Detect intent response - Unity and Dialogflow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dialogflow-es, gcloud

My code initially only returned the textual response. I've tried to add the audio response using  - [Detect Intent Response](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#detectintentresponse)    but am unsure if I have set it up correctly?

```
        UnityWebRequest postRequest = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
        RequestBody requestBody = new RequestBody();
        requestBody.queryInput = new QueryInput();
        requestBody.queryInput.audioConfig = new InputAudioConfig();
        requestBody.queryInput.audioConfig.audioEncoding = AudioEncoding.AUDIO_ENCODING_UNSPECIFIED;
        //TODO: check if that the sample rate hertz
        requestBody.queryInput.audioConfig.sampleRateHertz = 16000;
        requestBody.queryInput.audioConfig.languageCode = "en";
        requestBody.inputAudio = sampleString;

        requestBody.detectIntentResponse = new DetectIntentResponse();
        requestBody.detectIntentResponse.outputAudioConfig = new OutputAudioConfig();
        requestBody.detectIntentResponse.outputAudioConfig.outputAudioEncoding = OutputAudioEncoding.OUTPUT_AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16;
        requestBody.detectIntentResponse.outputAudioConfig.sampleHertzRate = 16000;


        string jsonRequestBody = JsonUtility.ToJson(requestBody, true);
        Debug.Log(jsonRequestBody);

        byte[] bodyRaw = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonRequestBody);
        postRequest.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
        postRequest.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler)new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
        postRequest.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler)new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        //postRequest.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        yield return postRequest.SendWebRequest();

            Debug.Log("Response: " + postRequest.downloadHandler.text);
            //text.text = "Response: " + postRequest.downloadHandler.text;


            // Or retrieve results as binary data
            byte[] resultbyte = postRequest.downloadHandler.data;
            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultbyte);
            ResponseBody content = (ResponseBody)JsonUtility.FromJson<ResponseBody>(result);
            Debug.Log(content.queryResult.fulfillmentText);

            text.text = "Response: " + content.queryResult.fulfillmentText;

            byte[] response = content.detectIntentResponse.outputAudio;
```

Once I have retrieved the audio, what would be the best approach to play the audio clip?

Comment: What format is your audio in?

Comment: 16 bit linear PCM

Answer (score 0):

So you'll want to wrap the data in an `AudioClip`, so it can be played by unity.
The easiest way is to create an `AudioClip` and using the `SetData(float[] data, int offsetSamples)` method

```
AudioSource audio = gameObject.AddComponent,AudioSource>() as AudioSource;
audio.clip.SetData(yourAudio, 0);
```